# postgres %I in format function

Tags: postgresql

I fail to understand the exact use of type `%I` in the `format` function. For example the use case below. How can datatype `regclass` be wrong for `%I` as `%I` is meant to 'treat the argument value as an SQL identifier'? When and how shall one use `%I`?

```
create schema myschema;          
create table myschema.mytable (c int);          

DO $$ 
DECLARE 
    v_sql text := format('analyze %I','myschema.mytable'::regclass); 
BEGIN 
    execute v_sql; 
END $$;

/*
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "myschema.mytable" does not exist
Where: SQL statement "analyze "myschema.mytable""
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at EXECUTE
*/
```

Comment: Your schema and your table are two different object names, you need two %I's. Casting to a regclass isn't needed, but doesn't hurt

Comment: It would need to be `analyze "myschema"."mytable"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myschema` and `mytable` are two separate identifiers. You'd need to use `format('analyze %I.%I', 'myschema', 'mytable')` to generate the SQL `analyze "myschema"."mytable"`.

Notice that when using a [`regclass` value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html), you don't need `%I` but `%s` does suffice:

> the output functions [for the object identifier types] will use double quotes if needed to make the output be a valid SQL identifier.